# Remover painel lateral do Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

É possível remover o painel lateral do Visual Studio Code?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O nome deste "painel" é *minimap*.

Você pode alterar a visibilidade dele alterando seu arquivo *settings.json* e adicionando um par de chave-valor com a chave `editor.minimap.enabled` e um valor *booleano*.

Esta configuração pode valer para todos os *workspaces*, se você o valor na aba *user settings*, ou apenas para o *workspace* atual, se editar na aba *workspace settings*.

Para abrir a edição deste arquivo, tecle <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**,**</kbd> (vírgula).

```
"editor.minimap.enabled": false
```

Answer (score 5):

Abra o `Visual Studio Code`, tecle o atalho `ctr + ,`. 
Neste momento vai aparecer essa caixa de comandos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nela digite: `editor.minimap.enabled` e aperte `enter`.
Vai ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que existe um icone em forma de lapis, clique nele e em seguida altere  para False.

Pronto, seu painel `minimap` foi ocultado.

**Ou simplesmente use o atalho `ctrl + B.`**