# Como diminuir Barra que exibe o numero de linhas e SideBar do VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Como eu não tenho dois monitores no meu computador, eu tenho que dividir a tela com as video aulas do meu curso de programação com o VsCode.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Remover painel lateral do Visual Studio Code](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216856/remover-painel-lateral-do-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

A barra da direita você pode abrir/remover da seguinte forma:

```
Ctrl + Shift + P > Toggle Minimap > Enter
```

A da esquerda não sei se tem como, e não te recomendaria remove-la pois saber as linhas pode te ajudar no processo de debug

Comment: queria tirar essa barra lateral
a que tem extensoes, arquivos e etc

Comment: @Skrill botao direito em cima > hide active sidebar.
A de arquivos é só vc empurrar pro lado oposto